# Supporting multiple versions with Successful Git Branching Model

Tags: git, versioning, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

At our company we are moving from SvN to Git (yeah, better late than never). With that, we also try to streamline the versioning process. To do that I found an interesting article: Successful Git Branching Model by Vincent Driessen.

As far as I can read from the article, developer assumes linear releases. To be clear:

```
v1.0.0 --> v1.0.1 --> v1.0.2 --> v1.1.0 --> v1.1.1 etc
```

Support for older releases is not mentioned. For example: we support up to three major versions back because some clients do not want to upgrade. So imagine we have the following versions:

```
v7.0.0 --> v8.0.0 --> v9.0.0 --> v10.0.0
```

When there is a critical bug found in `v8.0.0` **after** the release of `v9.0.0`, we checkout tag `v8.0.0`, fix bug, and merge it back into `develop` and `master` branches. Merge into `master` gets tag `v8.0.1`.

Seems to me somehow weird because of two things:

1. The `master` timeline will look like `v7.0.0 --> v8.0.0 --> v9.0.0 --> v8.0.1 --> v10.0.0`. I'm totally aware it's possible, but is it also acceptable?
2. When I merge from `hotfix` to `master` (and `master` is at that moment at `v9.0.0`) and tag it with `v8.0.1`, do I also get features introduced between `v8.0.0` and `v9.0.0`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, the tag `v8.0.1` should be the commit before the merge `master`. If you want to patch the new versions, then you merge the other tags there as well.

```
v8.0.0 --> v9.0.0 --> v10.0.0
   \          \           \
  v8.0.1 --> v9.0.1 --> v10.0.1/master
```

Comment: Thanks! I probably misunderstood the concepts of tagging in Git in first place :) Did'nt realized I can tag the hotfix itself, as opposed to merging into develop/master and then tagging. Thanks!